# Read and write to file buffer in different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

The problem I face here may be easy to solve.
I am reading in multiple files chosen by the users via `std::ifstream`. The whole reading is done in thread 1 and the file contents are copied to a buffer that is shared between the threads. Meanwhile another thread 2 is reading in what was written to the buffer.  I am thus far.
Could anybody give me a hint on how to implement this buffer fast and thread-safe?

Comment: Use an appropriate lock mechanism from the [C++ Thread Support Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread).

Comment: It will never be fast.  But should be thread safe.  When sharing buffers between threads there is only slow, and slower, and disfunctionally slow.  Dont do this unless its absolutely neccessary.  Which it often is.  And above all else make it safe.  If at all possible use a locking mechanism provided by the OS or target platform hardware.  These will generally be faster than a generic C++ mechanism which eventually bubbles down to the locking mechanism provided by the OS, or target platform hardware.  When in doubt use a critical section.

Comment: Never modify the buffer after you've made it available to another thread, and pass it to the other thread(s) via a shared_ptr rather than via a raw pointer.  If you follow those rules, the threads won't have to do any locking to safely read the buffer's data.  (note that you will need a thread-safe way to pass the shared_ptrs to the other threads; that's often done via a dequeue and a lock, but that shouldn't be a problem performance-wise as copying the shared_ptr is a cheap operation)